# dbus-monitoring loop exits automatically

Tags: bash, gnome, dbus

**I'm trying to execute a bash command on screen lock/unlock.**

Following tutorials & StackExchange questions, I came up with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do #added to try to solve the issue, but alas it did not
    dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" |
    while read sign; do
        case "$sign" in
            *"boolean false"*)  echo "Screen unlocked";;
            *"boolean true"*)   echo "Screen locked";;
        esac
    done
done
```

I launch the program with the following command:

```
nohup myprogram.sh &
```

**Everything works well at start, but after a while (several hours), there is no more echoed output when screen is locked/unlocked.**

Checking the output of `ps aux | grep mycommand`, I have the following result ***at start***:

```
user  <pid1> 0.0 0.0 <number> <number> pts/2 S 13:01   0.00 /bin/bash myprogram.sh
user  <pid2> 0.0 0.0 <number> <number> pts/2 S 13:01   0.00 /bin/bash myprogram.sh
```

After it breaks and does not emit messages anymore, **then the `ps` output only shows one line**.

I'm using **CentOS 6.5**, with **Gnome 2.28** (and I unfortunately cannot upgrade to any newer version).

---

Would you have any insight about what could be happening and/or how to investigate further?

---

Edit: corrected the `while true; then` syntax error

Comment: Not having run your code -- but personally I'd introduce a small sleep inside the loop.

Comment: Btw., the outer loop should also be `while true; do` etc.

Comment: Add a line  `*)   echo "\`date\` Unknown";;` to the case statement, and run the command as `nohup myprogram.sh </dev/null > $HOME/myprogram.out 2>&1 &`.

Answer (score 1):

The following script works for me on Linux Mint Cinnamon. Note 'cinnamon' instead of 'gnome'; if you're unsure as to what to use, run `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`, which should provide you with the name to use instead of cinnamon; for me:

```
me@localhost ~] echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
cinnamon
```

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do #added to try to solve the issue, but alas it did not
    dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.cinnamon.ScreenSaver'" |
    while read sign; do
        case "$sign" in
            *[Ff]alse*) echo "Screen unlocked";;
            *[Tt]rue*)  echo "Screen locked";;
            *)   echo "`date` Unknown";;
        esac
        sleep 0.250
    done
done
```

Run like so:

```
nohup ./myprogram </dev/null >| $HOME/myprogram.out 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" |
    while read -r sign; do
        case "$sign" in
            *"boolean false"*)  echo "Screen unlocked";;
            *"boolean true"*)   echo "Screen locked";;
        esac
    done
done
```

i change  `while true; then`  to `while true; do` and add option `-r` to `while read sign; do`